# Importing a matrix from Python to Pyomo

Tags: numpy, import, pyomo

I have a matrix defined in Python: (name of the document matrix.py)

```
N = 4
l = N
k = N


D = np.zeros((l,k))


for i in range(0,l):   
    for j in range(0,k):
        if (i==j):
            D[i,j] = 2
        else:
            D[i,j] = 0
D[0,0] = (2*N**2+1)/6   

D[-1,-1] = -(2*N**2+1)/6  


print(D)
```

I want to use it in Pyomo, and i did:

```
import matrix
```

.
.
.

```
m.f_x1 = Var(m.N)
def f_x1_definition(model,i):
    for j in m.N:
        return m.f_x1[j] ==sum(D[i,j]*m.x1[j] for j in range(value(m.n)))

m.f_x1_const = Constraint(m.N, rule = f_x1_definition)
```

But I get the next error: 
`NameError: global name 'D' is not defined`

How can I do it?

Comment: Variables defined in the `matrix.py` module have to be accessed with the `matrix.D` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But.. how sholud I do that?? I don´t know what you mean. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

When you import a module in python using the syntax

```
import foo
```

all the things defined in the `foo` module will be available within the `foo` namespace.  That is, if `foo.py` contains:

```
import numpy as np
a = 5
D = np.zeros((1,5))
```

when you import the module with `import foo`, then you can access `a`, and `D` with:

```
import foo
print(foo.a)
print(foo.D)
```

If you want to pull the symbols from `foo` directly into your local namespace, you would instead use the `from ... import ...` syntax:

```
from foo import a,D
print(a)
print(D)
```