# Pyomo summation of a product of a matrix by a vector

Tags: matrix, pyomo

I edit my code including all the parameters and variables involved:

(D is a numpy matrix imported from Python)

```
import pyomo
from pyomo.environ import *
from array import *


import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from diff_matrix import D  ##N=10????
print(D)


m =ConcreteModel()
...
m.n = Param(initialize = 10, within = Integers)               
m.Ns = Set(initialize = range(0,value(m.n)))   
m.x1 = Var(m.N, domain = Reals)
m.D = Param(m.N, m.N, initialize=D)

m.f_x1 = Var(m.N)
def f_x1_definition(model,i):
        return m.f_x1[i] == sum(m.x1[j]*m.D[i,j] for j in range(value(m.n)))
m.f_x1_const = Constraint(m.Ns, rule = f_x1_definition)
```

But I get the next error:

```
   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing is to just use the Python `sum()` function instead of the Pyomo `summation()` function:

```
def f_x1_definition(model,i):
    return model.f_x1[i] == sum(model.x1[j]*model.D[i,j] for j in range(value(model.n)))
```

Also, note that I reversed the order of the Pyomo `Var` (`m.x1`) and the matrix (`m.D`).  Based on your other questions ([Importing a matrix from Python to Pyomo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812375/importing-a-matrix-from-python-to-pyomo)), I am assuming that the matrix is a NumPy matrix.  When multiplying a NumPy value and a Pyomo component (`Var` or `Param`), always put the Pyomo object first.  This is due to a conflict between the NumPy operator overloading and the Pyomo operator overloading in current versions of Pyomo (up through at least 5.1).

---

**EDIT 1**: Note on reversing the order of operands: in your original question, it was not clear that `m.D` was being defined as a Pyomo `Param`.  There is no concern with the order of Pyomo objects in expressions.  The operator overloading problem mentioned above is *only* when multiplying NumPy objects with Pyomo components.  Further, at this time (up through Pyomo 5.1), Pyomo does not support matrix algebra - that is, operations like matrix-matrix or matrix-vector products.  Since every expression is a scalar expression, the ordering of the terms in a commutative operation (`+`, `*`) does not change the meaning of the expression.

**EDIT 2**: Your error has nothing to do with the `sum`/`summation` you originally posted.  The problem is with how you are initializing your Param.  At this time (up through Pyomo 5.1), you cannot directly initialize a Param from a `numpy.ndarray`.  You need to first convert the NumPy object into a Python dictionary with something like:

```
m.D = Param(m.N, m.N, initialize=dict(((i,j),D[i,j]) for i in m.N for j in m.N))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it, but I still have an error... ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()     Any idea? :)

Comment: You need to provide more of the model before we can diagnose your problem.  Specifically, how do you define `m.f_x1`, `m.x1`, and `m.D`.  Also note: if you use `model` as the first argument to the rule (function), then you need to use `model` inside the function.