# Initializing Params in Different ways gives me the same Attribute Error

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to use pyomo for solving a quadratic program. My model is below. I will add more constraints and objective at later stages.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()
model.IDX1 = range(96)
model.IDX2 = range(192)
model.IDX3 = range(49)

# Variables
model.x = Var(model.IDX1)

b2 = main_power2.iloc[[0]]
b2 = np.append([0], np.asarray(b2))

model.H_py  = Param(model.IDX1, initialize = arrtodict(Hp)) # Hp: 96*96
model.A1_py = Param(model.IDX2, initialize = arrtodict(A1l)) # A1l: 192 * 96
model.b1_py = Param(model.IDX2, initialize = arrtodict(b1)) # 192*1
model.A2_py = Param(model.IDX3, initialize = arrtodict(A2)) # 49 * 96
model.b2_py = Param(model.IDX3, initialize = arrtodict(b2)) # 49,1

def inequality_rule(model,i): # i = IDX2
        return sum(  model.A1_py[i][j] * model.x[j] for j in model.IDX1 ) <= model.b1_py[i]  
model.c1 = Constraint (model.IDX2, rule = inequality_rule )
```

where arrtodict is a function that converts array (1-D, 2-D)to dictionary and is shown below. The entire point of converting it to dictionary is that the parameter initialization is done using dictionary if I am not mistaken.

```
def arrtodict(your_array):
    your_array = your_array.tolist()
    dict_data = {key: value for key, value in enumerate(your_array)}

    if type(dict_data[0]) is list: 
        for key, value in dict_data.items():
            dict_data[key] = {k: v for k, v in enumerate(value)}
    elif type(dict_data[0]) is (float or int):
        pass
    else:
        print ('Check Your data')
    return dict_data
```

For some reason I keep on getting the following error:

```
 line 3530, in _generate_relational_expression

 if not (rhs.__class__ in native_types or rhs.is_expression_type()):

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'
```

And the error is exactly same if I try to use list/array to initialize the parameters. The only difference in the error is 'dict' changes to 'list/numpy.ndarray' in error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Additionally, I did look to the [question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833664/pyomo-summation-of-a-product-of-a-matrix-by-a-vector)That is why converted arrays to dictionary.

Comment: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/611. You might have to go into the source code of pyomo to implement `return float(np.random.rand(1))` for `Param()` function in order to fix it while waiting for the library creator to update it

Comment: I did see this issue before, but the recommendation didn't say anything about changing the source code of pyomo. Additionally, I am not sure which part that would be exactly in the source code of pyomo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by ycx there is a bug in Pyomo.  If you pass an object to Param initialize it tries to use it as an expression object instead of iterating through it and using the values to initialize the param.

What you need to do is change your code to use a function that returns the correct value for the inputs. See the example from the code doc:

https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/tutorials/param.py

```
# A parameter can be constructed with the _initialize_ option, which is a 
# function that accepts the parameter indices and model and returns the value
# of that parameter element:
#
def W_init(model, i, j):
    #
    # Create the value of model.W[i,j]
    #
    return i*j
model.W = Param(model.A, model.B, initialize=W_init)
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuation of my previous comment:

> github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/611. You might have to go into the
>   source code of pyomo to implement return float(np.random.rand(1)) for
>   Param() function in order to fix it while waiting for the library
>   creator to update it

You'll have to use your IDE and inspect into the `Param()` function (I am using Spyder, so it is `mouse highlight Param > mouse right-click > mouse click 'Go to definition'`. It should open up a `.py` file and you will be able to edit the source code from there to insert in the above return statement and solve the issue.

Comment: While it was a good explanation, I am not sure if it is a good idea to change the source code

Comment: @Shubhankar  Why not? The source code is just another python script located in Lib of your Python installation folder.

Comment: Because I might be running it on a server and someone else might be using the same package.